# Cache Steps in Bitbucket Pipeline Setup

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

My bitbucket pipeline is as below.

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install -y zip
            - zip -r web.zip .
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.2.5
```

When this runs on the bitbucket pipeline I can see that it always downloads the docker image and does the same actions every time I deploy, is there a way to cache the below steps in the pipeline?

```
pipe: atlassian/aws-code-deploy:0.2.5
2s
+ docker container run \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh:ro \
   --volume=/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker:ro \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/atlassian/aws-code-deploy:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/atlassian/aws-code-deploy \
   --workdir=$(pwd) \
   --label=org.bitbucket.pipelines.system=true \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID="$BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME="$BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN="$BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID="$BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE="$BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE="$BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID="$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_BRANCH="$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID="$BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY="$BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG="$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG" \
   --env=CI="$CI" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER="$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER="$BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER="$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN="$BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID="$BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_COMMIT="$BITBUCKET_COMMIT" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR="$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR" \
   --env=PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN="$PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID="$BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL="$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" \
   --env=DOCKER_HOST="tcp://host.docker.internal:2375" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPE_SHARED_STORAGE_DIR="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPE_STORAGE_DIR="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/atlassian/aws-code-deploy" \
   --env=APPLICATION_NAME="$APPLICATION_NAME" \
   --env=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" \
   --env=AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" \
   --env=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" \
   --env=COMMAND="deploy" \
   --env=DEPLOYMENT_GROUP="$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP" \
   --env=FILE_EXISTS_BEHAVIOR="OVERWRITE" \
   --env=IGNORE_APPLICATION_STOP_FAILURES="true" \
   --env=S3_BUCKET="$S3_BUCKET" \
   --env=VERSION_LABEL="-web-1.0.2" \
   --env=WAIT="true" \
   --add-host="host.docker.internal:$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" \
   bitbucketpipelines/aws-code-deploy:0.2.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the follow as an example for caching node

```
- step:
   caches:
     - docker
```

Comment: Does this node mean nodejs or the actual node it self?

Comment: Node as it stands would refer to any npm install, alternatively im your case as mentioned as an example I would recommend replacing node with docker. Do you have an example of your build process in pipelines? If so maybe update the question and lets see what caching type is required

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket Pipes are effectively just wrappers for `docker run` commands. You can see there isn't a `--pull always` flag in the output `run` command. So you can utilise the docker caching Pipelines can provide.

```
- step:
    script:
      - ...
    caches:
      - docker
```